# In Python's unittest library, why doesn't setUp() generate this runtime error?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am starting out with Python's `unittest` library. I'm trying to understand why instantiating a class that doesn't yet exist doesn't appear to cause any errors when using `setUp()`.

Here is the test code I have so far:

```
import queue
import unittest

class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_new_queue(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I haven't written anything in `queue`, so I'm expecting a runtime error. When I run the test suite, that's what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[omitted]/test_suite.py", line 6, in test_new_queue
    self.queue = queue.Queue()
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Now I move this into the setUp() method:

```
class TestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
```

But the result isn't what I expect:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Further references to `self.queue` don't cause any errors either.

What's going on here?

Comment: Python's stdlib has a module named [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). This is the module that is loaded by your test code. I suggest renaming your `queue` module so that it doesn't collide with Python's `queue`.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. @MichaelRuth I'd recommend adding this as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Ah, I had no idea! Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `queue.Queue()` failed in your first example. Did you have an empty `queue.py`? Did something change between these runs of the code?

Comment: As an aside, this isn't a compile time error. Its a runtime error.

Comment: @tdelaney hit the nail on the head. Removing my answer because it's incorrect and I can't improve on the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The python standard library also has a module named `queue`, but that isn't why your `setUp` example didn't fail. You could rename your module to `myqueue.py` and without a `Queue` defined in that .py file, you'd see the same thing.

From the docs, [unittest — Unit testing framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest)

> The setUp() and tearDown() methods allow you to define instructions
> that will be executed before and after each test method.

In both cases you imported your empty `queue.py`. But in your second case you had no test cases, so `setUp` was never run. Add any test method and `setUp` would fail.